Overlay HTML on an RTMP Feed
I'm working on a project for my local cricket club, I have an RTMP video feed from a HikVision camera, which I plan to feed to a nginx on a Raspberry Pi for redistribution.
I want to overlay an image and some API data from another source.
Could anyone advise on the best approach to this?
Would it be possible to build a Https presentation with the video embedded and then reencode as an RTMP stream.  Not really sure on the best approach so I can post for a freelancer.
Thanks
